# Correct Approach of following MVC

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working in MVC from last one year. I am following the MVC  approach i.e simple appraoch and not Repository patterns. Now, I come to know about the advantages of using Repository with dependency injection and I feel it follows the oops in right way.
That is my thinking. 
In one of my sample/test  project I started working with repositor and have few questions about it:::

1) when we use EDMX , suppose I have a table names "Users", it automattically 
   creates a class named as "users" which contains all the fields as properties.
What I usually follow is I create a model layer and add a class in that model layer of name 
"myUsers" that will contains same properties as the class users have.Now, I will bind the view
page with "myUsers" so that it cannot deal directly with DAL.

and Whenever I post something from my view page , the object comes in "MyUsers" model,
and here I again do something like this.
Users=MyUsers(I do this by doing this for each property like::
Users.Name=MyUsers.Name
and then I save it in Database.

I use above approach and in my applications I have used the above approach.
Now my question is
Can I bind my view page directly with "Users" class? As I see some applications,
it is happening. It reduced much work and also overheads in application.

What is correct approach ? to deal directly with DAL or there should be models 
in between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Correct approach" is subjective. We like to create ViewModels that exist purely to show domain objects in a view because it means we can separate view logic from the domain. We may not always want to show / load every property of a domain object. As another example, we put `DataAnnotation`s attributes for validation on our ViewModels.. but we leave the domain objects as nice little POCO's.

Manually mapping them like you are is an incredible waste of time though. There are frameworks that do that for you.. such as:

- [Automapper](http://automapper.org/)
- [ValueInjector](http://valueinjecter.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Sir, it means creating view models that acts as a seperate layer is better and to assign values to domain class, I can use the above frameworks suggested by you. Right Sir?

Comment: Remember though.. there is no right or wrong answer here. It is different for every project.

Comment: but just one thing more to ask Sir. Can I assume it is 80% right approach to follow on?

Answer (score 0):

According to me, this is the correct architecture.

Let me explain the answer in comments below.

[image]

Comment: That's really a good question. I was also facing same problems when I was new to MVC.
THe approach you are thinking is wrong. You cannot write that model in View directly, which you use to store in the database.
You are right, though your code will work properly but from attackers perspective, you have given direct access to your Database.

Comment: What? "Direct access to your database" ... ridiculous.

Comment: The words i used are totally wrong.I meant direct access as "breach in the code" (but not directly)